# BitmapFactory and HTTPUrlConnection issue

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with inserting image from URL. When I try to decode Stream from BitmapFactory, application crashed

onClick method

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                String temp = (String) extras.get("temp");

                String ikona = (String) extras.get("ikony");
                URLs = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+ikona+".png";
                Log.d("asd",URLs);

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(URLs);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()); // here is the problem
                    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Log.d("asd","malformedURLException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("asd","IOException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
```

Problem is in Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream())

```
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at pl.pawelfrydrych.realweather.Szczegoly$1.onClick(Szczegoly.java:55)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-18 21:38:55.049: E/AndroidRuntime(26374):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a Bitmap image from url directly run it on thread.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String temp = (String) extras.get("temp");

String ikona = (String) extras.get("ikony");
URLs = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+ikona+".png";
Log.d("asd",URLs);

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(URLs);
            Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent());
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
});
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not make a network call on the main thread. Do the bitmap decoding in a separate thread or in an AsyncTask. Also make sure that you have permission for internet.